How to convert Hyperoperation from recursion to iteration?
I’ve been exploring the hyperoperation sequence, which is typically defined recursively.

According to the same source, hyperoperations can be expressed using iteration, but the examples still appear to rely on recursion at their core. The recursive definition of hyperoperations uses the result of the previous level to compute the next result, which seems inherently recursive.

But Wikipedia also said:

Every recursive function can be transformed into an iterative function by replacing recursive calls with iterative control constructs and simulating the call stack with a stack explicitly managed by the program.

However, despite reading the section on "Iteration of Hyperoperation" on Wikipedia, I’m still unclear on how to completely convert these recursive definitions into an iterative form. So my question is: Can the recursive nature of hyperoperations be entirely removed?
If it can be transformed into an iterative version, how can this be achieved without relying on recursion? Any clarification or examples of how to make hyperoperations purely iterative would be greatly appreciated such as a pseudocode that purely using while and for syntax only.
